# using IEEEtran document class -- how to align multiple rows of author

Tags: titles, ieeetran

Say I am using IEEE Transactions journal class

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

How I should align the author properly so that it appears in this format?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In conference mode you already have the `\IEEEauthorblockN` for (N)ame and `\IEEEauthorblockA` for (A)ffilition of each author in the column format. You then introduce line breaks in the same cell to put the second ones. The columns are seperated by `\and` commands.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<---- For dummy text
\title{Some IEEE paper}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}\\   %<------ Line breaks in the current column
\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}\\[0.9cm]  %<------- Extra vertical space
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\
and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}\\                 %<-----------
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\
and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add some whole width `IEEEauthorblockA` between the author blocks and the beguining of the document?
Something like

Comment: Why doesn't it come out like this with just using `\and` between each author?

Comment: +1, this looks really nice. One thing that is a bit confusing though is that the authors are listed in different order in the source and in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to reference [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458208/8920) to a similar question (in this case with 5 authors).

They introduce a new command `\linebreakand` to use in place of `\and` at the end of a row of authors:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linebreakand}{%
  \end{@IEEEauthorhalign}
  \hfill\mbox{}\par
  \mbox{}\hfill\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}
}
\makeatother
```

With this command, the list of authors remains in the same order in the source and in the paper. Please see the [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458208/8920) for an example and explanation.