# IEEEtran seven authors

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64734/using-ieeetran-document-class-how-to-align-multiple-rows-of-author) question which showed how to add 6 authors to an Ieee paper.

How can I do this to add seven authors in this format? I'd like 4 on the first line and three on the second line. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum} %<---- For dummy text
\title{Some IEEE paper}


\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
Some University\\
email@example.com}\\  
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Five}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
Some University\\
email@example.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Two}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Some University\\
email@example.com}\\
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Six}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Some University\\
email@example.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Three}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Some University\\
email@example.com}\\              
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Seven}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Some University\\
email@example.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Four}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Some University\\
email@example.com}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make it so that the authors on the first line are centered and the authors on the second line are centered? In other words, I don't want the authors in the two rows to be vertically aligned to each other, but instead to be centered in their own row?

Also, is this the proper way to add seven authors in conference style?

Comment: I'm interested in the same question, except for five authors.

Comment: @JacopoNotarstefano any success?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dug into exactly how they've done it - but the [RLDM template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/rldm-the-multi-disciplinary-conference-on-reinforcement-learning-and-decision-making-template/cgxmvpscgwfh) seems to do what you want (and also what Jacopo wants re 5 authors).

Note that they seem to use /And for the next author and \AND to force a new line.

[image: Screenshot showing 7 authors]