# Authors with log affiliations IEEE

Tags: horizontal-alignment, templates, ieeetran

I'm relatively new in this LaTex thing. I'm unable to align 4 authors because the affiliations are too big. I saw some answers like [using IEEEtran document class -- how to align multiple rows of author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64734/using-ieeetran-document-class-how-to-align-multiple-rows-of-author) doesn't work. Here there is an equivalent code:

```
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{The Greate department of the planet and univers GDPU\\
The Good Univesity of the Planet and Univers GUPU\\
My, Contry\\
my@cdpu.bupu.cy}\\   %<------ Line breaks in the current column
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{The coolest department of the planet and univers CDPU\\
The Best Univesity of the Planet and Univers BUPU\\
My, Contry\\
my@cdpu.bupu.cy}\\[0.9cm]  %<------- Extra vertical space
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{The nicer department of the planet and univers NDPU\\
The Better Univesity of the Planet and Univers BUPU\\
My, Contry\\
my@cdpu.bupu.cy}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Name Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{The cool department of the planet and univers CDPU\\
The Even Better Univesity of the Planet and Univers EBUPU\\
My, Contry\\
my@cdpu.bupu.cy}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you broke a too-large institution name into two lines, it would look a lot better than it does now.

Comment: what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this format of the author list? Alternatively, you could create an author block, where all names appear in one (or more) lines and the affiliations below.

```
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{First Name\textsuperscript{1},
Second Name\textsuperscript{2}, Third Name\textsuperscript{1}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textsuperscript{1} First Institution}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textsuperscript{2} Second Institution}
}
```